# Redshift Enhanced VPC Routing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

**Question:** What are the downsides (if any) to enabling Enhanced VPC Routing on an Amazon Redshift cluster?

According to the documentation, there is no extra charge and traffic is prevented from traveling over the public internet. Why wouldn't this be a default option always enabled?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/enhanced-vpc-routing.html

- If Enhanced VPC Routing is not enabled, Amazon Redshift routes traffic through the internet, including traffic to other services within the AWS network.
- There is no additional charge for using Enhanced VPC Routing. You might incur additional data transfer charges for certain operations. These include such operations as UNLOAD to Amazon S3 in a different AWS Region. COPY from Amazon EMR, or Secure Shell (SSH) with public IP addresses.

**Background:** We have a Redshift cluster that intermittently drops ODBC connections with a TCP reset, but only when enhanced VPC routing is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

The Query Editor in the Redshift console does not support clusters with Enhanced VPC Routing enabled. That is the only downside that I know of.